# Apache Phoenix unable to create schema

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, sqlline

I am using Apache Phoenix and trying to create schema.

Following are the versions used (psuedo-distributed installation)

1. Hadoop  - 2.6.4
2. Hbase   - 1.1.2
3. Phoenix - 4.7.0
4. Sqlline - 1.1.8
5. Zookeper- 3.4.6 (Hbase default/ managed)

I am ale to create schemas

hbase-site.xml

`<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://{{HOST}}:8020/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/testuser/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>{{HOST}}</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
        <value>/hbase</value>
        <source>hbase-site.xml</source>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>`

an getting following error

`0: jdbc:phoenix:hdp1.hw.com:2181> !tables
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| TABLE_CAT  | TABLE_SCHEM  | TABLE_NAME  |  TABLE_TYPE   | REMARKS  | TYPE_NA |
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
|            | SYSTEM       | CATALOG     | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |         |
|            | SYSTEM       | FUNCTION    | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |         |
|            | SYSTEM       | SEQUENCE    | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |         |
|            | SYSTEM       | STATS       | SYSTEM TABLE  |          |         |
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
0: jdbc:phoenix:hdp1.hw.com:2181> create schema test;
Error: ERROR 601 (42P00): Syntax error. Encountered "schema" at line 1, column 8. (state=42P00,code=601)
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 601 (42P00): Syntax error. Encountered "schema" at line 1, column 8.
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException.newException(PhoenixParserException.java:33)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:111)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$PhoenixStatementParser.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1185)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1268)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1339)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
Caused by: NoViableAltException(98@[])
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.oneStatement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:650)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.statement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:500)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:108)
    ... 9 more`

However using `phoenix 4.14.0` i am able to create schema's successfully with same configuration.

Comment: maybe tried this create schema IF NOT EXISTS test;